# Removing apostrophes from database values to be passed as function parameters

Tags: javascript, html, json

I'd like to remove apostrophes from strings when passing them as parameters to a function.

But, I need to escape them inside a function call (or before) since I do not know the values that will be passed (db variables I can't escape from the database).

```
onclick="editName(\''+JSON.stringify(service['name']).replace("'","")+'\',\''+id+'\');
```

This removes the apostrophe, but adds extra quotes and a space before the first parameter. It looks like this:

`onclick="editName('" testers"','919');"=""></i>`

The ideal output should look like:

`onclick="editName('testers','919');"=""></i>`

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: The first code has unbalanced quotes: the first double quote is never closed, and the first (non-escaped) quote seems to close something that was never opened. Could you please provide the correct *code* (including all quotes that start/end string literals)?

Answer (score 1):

```
onclick="editName(\''+service['name'].toString().split("'").join('')+'\',\''+id+'\');
```